# Initial path slash being stripped out when form submitted

Tags: 9

I'm on Drupal 9.4.5. All of a sudden, anytime I click a submit button, the domain and path are smushed together without a slash between them.

So what should be this:
`https://ylndev.yln.info/admin/config/yln/new_employee/settings`
is actually coming out as this:
`https://ylndev.yln.infoadmin/config/yln/new_employee/settings`

In the HTML, I do see the path as beginning with a slash. This is only happening with submit buttons, not other types of links.

The only thing I've done recently is update modules and the core. I've tried rolling back but this problem persists. I've searched everywhere I can think of and I've checked some of the modules' open tickets to no avail. I'm hoping someone knows a fix or which module might have caused this. Thanks!

**Update**: this is the form code. It's not specific to this form -- it's happening in all forms in Drupal, both core and third-party.

```
<?php
/**
  *@file
  *Contains \Drupal\new_employee\Form\New_employeeSettingsForm
  */
  
namespace Drupal\new_employee\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class New_employeeSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {
    /**  
   * {@inheritdoc}  
   */ 
    protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
        return [
            'new_employee.settings',
        ];
    }
    
    /**  
   * {@inheritdoc}  
   */ 
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'new_employee_settings';
    }
    
    /**  
   * {@inheritdoc}  
   */ 
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $config = $this->config('new_employee.settings');
        
        $form['new_employee_email'] = [
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => $this->t('Destination Email for Requests'),
            '#description' => $this->t('Set the destination email for new employee requests.'),
            '#default_value' => $config->get('new_employee_email'),
        ];
        return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    }
    
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $email = $form_state->getValue('new_employee_email');
        if ($email == !\Drupal::service('email.validator')->isValid($email)) {
            $form_state->setErrorByName('new_employee_email', t('The email address %mail is not valid.', array('%mail' => $email)));
        }
    }   
    
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
                
        $this->config('new_employee.settings')
            ->set('new_employee_email', $form_state->getValue('new_employee_email'))
            ->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your form and submit handler? it could be some non-traditional submit handler and/or custom submit button.

Comment: It's all submit buttons across the app. For example, if I edit a book page and click the button at the bottom, it throws an error because the slash is missing.

Comment: post the code for the form `admin/config/yln/new_employee/settings`

Comment: I added the code to the original post.

Comment: Oops, I put in the code for the wrong form so I've updated it. Same difference, though, because they both do have the slash problem.

Comment: it looks fine to me and if this is happening on all forms then as the original comment suggestedit's likely something else. when you updated core and contrib did you update the database as well? I'd suggest trying updb if not already done; clearing cache, exporting configuration ...etc